# SHA384 is not supported by your openssl extension, could not verify the phar file integrity

Tags: php, composer-php

I get the error when i run `composer self-update` on Windows 10
Here is the full error message

```
     composer self-update
     Updating to version 1.8.4 (stable channel).
     Downloading (100%)


     [RuntimeException]
    SHA384 is not supported by your openssl extension, could not verify the phar file integrity
```

I am running `PHP 7.3.2`
What could be the problem?

Comment: You're using an old version of composer. Try and completely remove it and install the latest version from scratch. [Here's a Github issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7802) about this error message.

Comment: you need to unistall composer <= 1.7.2 and then install a new version of composer >= 1.7.3 to avoid that update error for all future update type installs

Comment: @MagnusEriksson reinstalling worked

Comment: Or you can first switch back to php 7.2, then run composer selfupdate.
If that was successful, you can switch to php 7.3, or 7.4.

Answer (score 221):

Remove Your older versions and install the latest version of Composer,

Remove Your older version: 
`sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/composer`

Download the installer:
`sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

Move the composer.phar file:
`sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: Actually it's not even required to remove the old version. Just install new one and move `composer.phar`

Comment: In some machine and installation, It's a good thing also to execute the command 

"chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer" 

to make it executable.

Comment: The OP is using Windows OS, so those commands don't apply.

Comment: This also worked for me in a Docker container that was reporting the same openssl problem.

Comment: Thx! Here "sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php" what does "| php" stand for?

Answer (score 31):

Manually update the composer:

```
wget -cO - https://getcomposer.org/composer-stable.phar > /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Check the installed composer version:

```
composer --version
```

Answer (score 7):

The error means you are using `composer` of version `1.7.2`or below.
You have to uninstall composer and then install a `composer` version `1.7.3` and above.

Answer (score 2):

I've just experienced the same issue on my Windows machine.  I'd just downloaded and installed Composer from https://getcomposer.org/download/ and when I tried to run `php composer-setup.php` it failed with "SHA384 is not supported by your openssl extension".

The solution that worked for me was to perform the command line install (documented on the same site). Visit https://getcomposer.org/download/ to get the latest SHA.

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'c5b9b6d368201a9db6f74e2611495f369991b72d9c8cbd3ffbc63edff210eb73d46ffbfce88669ad33695ef77dc76976') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can download latest version from [https://getcomposer.org/](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and just replace the file **composer.phar** in your **composer** folder, in my machine this is installed in windows at **C:\composer**

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Manually update the composer(Uninstall and install)

**Solution 2:**

The error means you are using composer version 1.7.2 or below. Uninstall composer and then install a composer version 1.7.3 and above.

or

```
composer self-update --rollback and run composer self-update.
```