# Laravel 8 Installer error -- The "--remove-vcs" option does not exist

Tags: composer-php, laravel-8

I've recently install new Laravel Installer to get version 8 I was having the following error:

```
| |                             | |
| |     __ _ _ __ __ ___   _____| |
| |    / _` | '__/ _` \ \ / / _ \ |
| |___| (_| | | | (_| |\ V /  __/ |
|______\__,_|_|  \__,_| \_/ \___|_|


                                                          
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "--remove-vcs" option does not exist.               
                                                          

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

I thought primarily that was the installer of laravel and didn't find any article about, but the problem was in my composer that need update.

For it I tried:

```
composer self-update
```

And I got

```
[RuntimeException]
SHA384 is not supported by your openssl extension, could not verify the phar file integrity
```

So the process would be uninstall Composer and install again

To remove:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/composer
```

To install:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
```

Making composer Global:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Test Composer:

```
composer
```

Finally I installed laravel again.

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Comment: Have you followed ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/54983039/4650866